# Validator "Restore" returned fail status on WAMP

Tags: php, cs-cart

trying to upgrade from 4.3.3sp1 to 4.3.4 on my localhost ( WAMP ).

However on the validation step it fails with:

```
 Validation issue 
 Validator "Restore" returned fail status Unable to
 prepare restore script.
```

Tried changing file permissions and some other things I found on Google.

Did not manage to find any additional data about this even on their bugtracker.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

CS-Cart is trying to build the restore file name with this rule:

```
$target_restore_file_name = 'restore_' . date('Y-m-d_H:i:s', TIME) . '.php';
```

But Windows does not allow ":" in the filenames. So a workaround would be to do something like this:

```
$target_restore_file_name = 'restore_' . date('Y-m-d_His', TIME) . '.php';
```

Or other variations.

This code is in app/Tygh/UpgradeCenter/App.php in the prepareRestore() function

Hope this will help someone